# How to use a lookup table in entity?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have imported my database into entity. All is well except my lookup tables aren't easily accessible anymore.

Example I have a Users table and a Friends table. Many unique users can have the same friends. To handle this I have a Users_Friends table consisting of 2 columns (UserID and FriendID).

I want to be able to query this table against a unique userID to pull all the FriendIDs associated with that particular user. But when I try and do

```
using (var db = new GameAlertDBEntities())
{
    var friendIDs = db.Users_Friends.
}
```

I immediately get told cannot resolve symbol Users_Friends. Which I stop there trying to figure out how to resolve the symbol before moving forward. Oddly enough entity finds all my other tables just none of my look up tables.

Comment: are you sure that `UserId` and `FriendId` marked as foreign key and both combined as composite primary key ?

Comment: Yes FK_Users_Friends_Friends and FK_Users_Friends_Users are present when I view them in SQL. Not sure if they are combined as a composite primary key though.

Comment: ill suggest you to re-create entities n check ! other then that rest seems fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many-to-many relationships aux tables are not abstracted into EF tables. Instead you can directly acceess list of related entities like this:

```
using (var db = new GameAlertDBEntities())
{
    var user = db.Users.First(); // or any other query for user
    var friends = user.Friends;
}
```

How does this happen? Entity framework recognizes such relationships during import and does all the work behind the scenes.

Comment: This worked. Very interesting stuff. Curiously, how would i save a into my lookup table. Example User creates a friend. How does the lookup table get these ids inserted into it? Does that make sense?

Comment: @allencoded then you insert new object into `Friends` list, EF will automatically create necessary entries in the `Users_Friends` table for you.

Comment: Thanks so much. One final question. A User logs in and tries to add a friend. The code determines this friend already exists. Instead of duplicating the friend it needs to go to the Users_Friends and Insert UserId with the currently matched FriendId. How does entity handle this scenario since I can't directly make Inserts into the lookup?

Comment: @allencoded you can't really create a "same" new Friend entity. You always get a Friend from a Friends set. If you work this way all works fine. If that doesn't help, I guess it's better to create a new question with a concrete example.

Comment: Thank you so much Petr you have been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

If UserId and FriendId are not marked as foreign key then you have to find friends by simple query

```
var userFriends = db.Users.Friends.ToList();
```